# App gets continuous low memory crashes only in Android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-account

I have an App tested on many devices and in various Android Emulator configurations, now I have tried to test the same App on the Android L emulator and get too often out of memory crashes,

I have tried to

- double the AVD memory from 512mb to 1024mb(note that in all others Android API Level configuration for the emulator the app works fine on 512mb)
- add

  android:largeHeap="true"
  to the manifest

but App crash in the same way with this error

```
09-29 12:20:20.528        0-927/? E/lowmemorykiller﹕ Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer
09-29 12:20:20.751      934-934/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
09-29 12:20:20.751      934-934/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
09-29 12:20:20.751      934-934/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
09-29 12:20:20.751      934-934/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
```

The Activity where I get the most crashes has no memory intensive routine is only a form and has no large images, only 2 little png thumb (200kb file size 300x300 original dimensions), 3 base spinner with only text rows, 3 edit text all in a scroller, no problem in any real or virtual device before Android L, only in Android L emulator get these issues... at the moment there aren't real devices with android L to know if the issue is related to some bug in the L emulator, but sounds pretty strange that in this version such Activity can get a low memory issue.

Any suggestion to improve the memory management or whatever things coul help me to fix this issue?

How to increase the heap limit of the emulator and how this could difers from real devices or previous emulator sdk version?!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an Android Lollipop issue - it has memory leaks. My apps also crash on 5.0.1, but run fine on other devices and emulators.